# CSS Drop Shadow for CSS drawn arrow

Tags: css, shadow

I want the arrow that appears when a div is hovered [here](http://bfcards.edicypages.com/list-of-cards/abyssal-warder-fire) to also drop a shadow. The arrow is drawn from CSS:

```
.arrow {
position:absolute;
margin-top:-50px;
left:80px;
border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ccff66;
border-style:solid;
border-width:20px;
width:0;
height:0;
z-index:3;
_border-left-color: pink;
_border-bottom-color: pink;
_border-top-color: pink;
_filter: chroma(color=pink);
}
```

The shadow setting I want to apply is:

```
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 0px 5px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0px 5px #888;
box-shadow: 1px 0px 5px #888;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=0, Color='#888888')";
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=0, Color='#888888');
```

The problem in just pasting the shadow setting into the arrow is that the shadow applies to the entire span box and results in a box shadow instead of an drop shadow for the arrow.

P.S. I want to try as much as possible to not use [explorercanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/), since I'm trying to minimize script tags in the html. However, if its a must please do provide the code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Applying the box shadow to the css border triangle will not work, it will only ever apply it to the whole element box.

You can achieve what you are trying to do by changing your css border triangle into a square div, rotating it 45 degrees using css3 and then applying the box-shadow

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(45deg);
transform: rotate(45deg);
position: absolute;
```

**Edit:**
Updated

**Edit:**
See the link below for another approach using css `content` and `:after`

http://css-tricks.com/triangle-with-shadow/

Comment: +1. This is probably the closest you're going to get using pure CSS. Of course, it only works if your triangle has a right-angled corner. You'll also need to play with z-index to ensure that the rotated box is layered behind the main box, but in front of the main box's shadow (hmm, tricky?). Finally, if you're supporting IE, you'll already be using a `filter` style for the shadow; be aware of how filters interract (or not) when applying the rotation as well.

Comment: Also, I wasn't aware that `BasicImage` supported 45 degree roataions; I though you had to use the `Matrix` filter for anything other than 90/180/270. Ref http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532918%28v=vs.85%29.aspx but if you've got a better link I'd be interested in seeing it.

Comment: @Blowsie: Just a clarification, is this compatible with IE6? Also, how do I cut it into a triangle?

Comment: Just added -o-transform: rotate(45deg); and it will work for Opera

Comment: @UrBestFriend - Thanks ive added the opera vendor specific code & I'm unaware if this works in IE6 as my company and I no longer develop for it.

Comment: @Spudley Indeed rotation=5 is invalid, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Blowsie: Tried the new codes for IE and sadly it doesn't work (even for IE9). I really hate IE

Comment: @UrBestFriend - Did you manage to get the rotation to work based on spudleys comment?

Comment: @Blowsie: The code only works for IE9; for IE6.7 and 8 the whole page's layout is broken... though I'm not sure if its the rotation or the other filters.

Comment: Btw found this good resource for rotations and other cs3 effects: http://css3please.com/ And this for gradients: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: @UrBestFriend - IE6/7/8 require `filter` style with the `Matrix` attribute for rotations. IE9 uses standard CSS3 and doesn't support `filter`, so you should be able to use the `transform` style with it, though it's possible it may need an `-ms-` prefix.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested other browsers, but I noticed that [CSS Arrow Please](http://cssarrowplease.com/) uses a neat little trick

**Using this syntax on the parent box will also add a dropshadow to the generated "arrow":**

```
 -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3));
```

**But using this syntax will not?:**

```
-webkit-box-shadow:  2px 3px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
```

Answer (score 2):

Credit to Blowsie for the original answer that led me to the following implementation.  Here is a [working jsfiddle implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/error454/aaDY9/) for Chrome.  The relevant CSS:

```
/* Make an arrow */
.arrow{
    background-color: pink;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;

    /* Translate the box up by width / 2 then rotate */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px) rotate(45deg);
}​
```

**Caveat**

If the content of your box overlaps the arrow then the illusion is broken.  You might try working around this by changing the z-index of the arrow to be behind the box but this will cause the box drop-shadow to be rendered on top of the arrow.  Add sufficient padding to the box content so that this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

I’m afraid drop shadows only apply to the element box, rather than the angle of the border corners. If you want an arrow like this with a drop-shadow, I’m afraid you’ll have to make it as a PNG image, with the drop shadow in the image.

CSS generally only produces square boxes. The border trick to make a pointy arrow here with CSS is a clever hack.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve arrow with shadow, which will work for all the browsers is to use html triangle character in unicode.

HTML:

```
 <span class="arrow">▶</span>
```

CSS:

```
.arrow {
  color: red;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
  transform: scaleY(1.4)
}
```

Since that is rendered as regular text you may apply the **text-shadow** property. For customize the arrow dimensions (want to add extra width or height or skew the arrow) **css3 transform property** is the key.
Here is reference with html characters: http://www.copypastecharacter.com/graphic-shapes
Enjoy