# How to auto margin-left for the message bar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a message which displaces on hover.
My code:

**CSS:**

```
.showtext:hover:before {
content: attr(data-content);
padding: 0.8em 1em;
position: absolute;
color: #fff;
background: #47a3da;
margin-left: 5%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="showtext" data-content="Message">Hover Me</span>
```

I have set `margin-left` to `5%` but it doesn't work all the time. It overlaps when the text inside span is longer, so how can I set it to auto `margin-left` a little, say `10px`?

I have tried to set to `auto` but it didn't work.
Also, how can I add a triangle at the left of the message so it points on the span text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, `margin-left` is applied to the left edge of the `.showtext` element. What you're trying to do is display the box 5% off the *right* edge, instead.

Simply change the `:before` selector to `:after` to solve your problem, so that your hover box is applied *after* the element rather than *before* it.

As for your second question, I'd recommend doing a search on SO for that; it has been answered more than once (I know; I've seen the questions).

Comment: Please provide links of few.

Comment: And may be a bumb question but what are these appearing message box called so I an search online for few nice ones ?

Comment: @user3452098 it's called "Tooltip"

Comment: @user3452090 Or even just "CSS arrows": http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/11/22/css-quick-tip-css-arrows-and-shapes-without-markup/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549594/css-drop-shadow-for-css-drawn-arrow