# Triangular pseudo-before element dropshadow

Tags: css

Is it possible to add a triangular drop shadow to a triangular pseudo-before element?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/by6Levo4/) of what I have so far.

```
<div class="list">
    <a>list item one</a>
    <a class="current">list item two</a>
    <a>list item three</a>
    <a>list item four</a>
</div>


.list a {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        height: 22px;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        background-color: #fff;  
        width: 100px;
}

.list a.current {
        background-color: aqua;  
        -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 1px 0px #ccc;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px 0px #ccc;
        box-shadow:         3px 3px 1px 0px #ccc;
}

.list a.current:before {
        content: " ";
        display: block;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-top: 22px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 22px solid transparent;
        border-left: 10px solid aqua;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -22px;
        left: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 1px 0px #ccc;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px 0px #ccc;
        box-shadow:         3px 3px 1px 0px #ccc;
     }

.list a.current:after {
        content: " ";
        display: block;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-top: 22px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 22px solid transparent;
        border-right: 10px solid aqua;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -22px;
        right: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
     }
```

Comment: I don't think so. Use an image instead..

Comment: Yes, using `filter:dropshadow` but it's not well supported

Comment: I would use @George approach

Comment: Hi dippas - what do you mean - the @George approach?

Comment: @NicholasMurray the comment vanished, but the guy was referring to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549594/css-drop-shadow-for-css-drawn-arrow?lq=1 , and I meant this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5549786/3448527

Comment: @dippas - thanks for digging the link out